# Illegal assignment from integer to string Error received

Tags: apex, compile-error

I am getting Illegal assignment from integer to string Error

```java
*//Map declaration*
Map<String, integer> PhoneMap = new Map<String, integer>();

*//adding Map values*
PhoneMap.put('IPhone',100000);
PhoneMap.put('Pixel',20000);
PhoneMap.put('Samsung',30000);
PhoneMap.put('LG',25000);

system.debug(PhoneMap);

set<string> tempSet = new set<String>();
tempSet = PhoneMap.keyset();

for(string VarOfKey: tempSet){
    system.debug('The current key is '+VarOfKey);
    string VarForValue = PhoneMap.get(VarOfKey);
    system.debug('The value of above key is '+VarForValue);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I've helped format your question to make it easier to read (removed a handful of blank lines, formatted as a code block, etc...). Usually, when you get an error, it really helps if you provide the error message _and stack trace_ (which tells you which line the error is on). My formatting would screw up line numbers, but the code is short enough in this case that it's easy to see the issue.

Comment: Thank you Derek

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that error because you're trying to assign an integer to a string.
Apex is a "strongly typed" language, so you need to pay attention to the type of data held in variables, returned from methods, etc...

The error is on this line

`string VarForValue = PhoneMap.get(VarOfKey);`

As the error indicates, an integer (which is what you're getting back from `PhoneMap.get()`, due to how you declared the map) can't be assigned to a string, so you'll need to make a change in your code to make it syntactically correct.

You could

- Change the type of the "value" of your map
- Change the type of `varForValue`
- Use one of the methods that Salesforce provides to convert between types (`String.valueOf()`, Integer's `valueOf()` method, Integer's `.format()` method)

Comment: Damn... I feel so stupid. Only if i had changed the datatype of 'VarForValue'  . Why didnt i see that. I just changed it from string to integer and it worked. Thanks